# Source Code Management for Development with MVC Frameworks

Tags: php, git, version-control, laravel

I am working on a small web project, using a PHP framework and I would like to check my development into some source code management for easy deployment to different environments. I chose Laravel and Git, but I guess the exact systems are not important for this question.

I am unsure what exact folder structure is best to be submitted to the source control.  Should I:

1. check in the whole framework, including the config files?
2. check in the "application" and "public" parts into separate repositories, but leave the config and system files out of source control?

If `1.`, how do I make sure that I am not overwriting deployment specific configs (i.e. dev, qa, prod) when I do a commit/push/pull.

If `2.`, how do I make sure that I keep the non-committed parts of the app in sync.

Any help/guidelines/best practices would be appreciated.

Comment: you can add file that should be ignored when you do a commit: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check everything in and use Laravel's [environments support](http://laravel.com/docs/install#environments).  It sounds as if you're maintaining separate configs for separate environments, instead of using the built in features.

Alternatively, you could try creating a repository for the app, and a repository for each config, and pull both the app and the relevant configs when testing.